# Django module to shorten css classes in production

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a css class:

```
.footer-react-btn{
  color:#ddd;
}
```

But if I change `.footer-react-btn` to `.a` or `.b`, then I might save some bytes of text from being loaded.

I want it to happen in my production. I will be writing the code in an understandable manner during my development.

So, Is there any way I can do it in?

I am new here. I need an explanation step by step.

Comment: Quite pointless. The only way that kind of minimization actually creates measurable improvement for end users is if your code was *absurdly* large and overcomplicated already, which would merit just making your code less that.

Comment: Yes. My code is large. And it will be even more larger if I go on adding new features to my website.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one simply maintains two files -- `a-stylesheet.css` and `a-stylesheet.min.css`. And it's usually limited to removing whitespace, not changing names. Imagine if you were using two different stylesheets and applied this same name-changing mechanism to both... You could suddenly have collisions that otherwise wouldn't exist. Plainly, just not a good idea.

At any rate, the closest thing to what you're looking for is [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) which combines and minifies your static JS/CSS, but it has many behaviors you may or may not want.

Frankly, it's my opinion that worrying about those few bytes is a waste of time. Simply minifying the CSS is a simpler and safer way to reduce the size of your CSS components. I wouldn't even consider more complex solutions until you *really* encounter scaling problems.

Comment: No. I don't think so. I have gone through the css of facebook and instagram. Their css is minified the same way I wanted it to be. And as of your suggestion, I have already been using `compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter` for minification of my css. But I don't think it is enough. When the user-base increases, it becomes an hectic problem to deliver such amounts of data. I would like to have everything small and simple.

Comment: @PresentationBuddies Facebook is at the scale for which implementing a solution to this problem might make sense. Facebook historically has battled CSS issues for a long time with many talented engineers working at this problem... Their solution is likely highly customized for their environment. For you, premature optimization is only going to hurt you in the long-run.  Keeping your project implementation small and simple is far more important than keeping your CSS files small and simple. Optimization is the *last* thing you do in a project! There are also much better ways to tackle this.

Comment: How does premature optimization hurt me in the long run? I want to keep my project small and simple. I need a module similar to `django-compressor`, which compresses the css files and stores them in `CACHE` folder and delivers them to the client. It does not affect my development. The code is not minimized during development. I want something similar. But it should also modify my html and javascript files likewise, making the code even smaller. And Optimization isn't the last thing to do in a project. The code becomes complicated, if we don't optimize it from the beginning of the project.

Comment: If you really want to, you can extend `django-compressor` to suit your needs or otherwise make the changes in your deployment process to accommodate this solution. My professional opinion is that the solution incurs real and significant costs while the benefits are certainly insignificant. In my view, you are gravely underestimating the costs here and are failing to consider the possible problems that arise from this. If you're truly committed, [this project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css-names) appears to be relevant. But I recommend against this decision highly. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

If you wants to see the fully expanded code in text editor and wants to send the minified css code to clients, use PHP comments.
First of all, make a file with extension **php**. Eg:- styles.php then add below code into it:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Then add the minified code. For removing the read-hardness issue, you could add PHP comments like 
You just add as many short codes as you wish but don't forget to enter the expanded information inside a PHP comment. The reason I suggested PHP comment instead css comments, is that PHP codes won't be executed by the web server. You can read both minified code and the expanded code(in comments) in the text editor but client browsers will only get the minified code loaded. So, you can decrease that data transferred....
I think that this will be helpful....

Comment: Are you looking for an answer like this one?

Comment: The OP has asked to minimize the css while in production. Not during development, which makes the code complicated and messy.

Comment: Do you wants to have the code containing the full text **footer-react-btn** in text editor and only pass the short form to client browsers?

Comment: yes. I need to serve the minified css and html files to my clients.

Comment: But you also needs to see the fully expanded code in the text editor right?

Comment: Man. All I need is a module that converts my files into the minimum way possible and delivers them from a converted folder to the client. So, yes, the code does not change in my editor.

Comment: What is this? Don't you see the tags? It's Python. Not PHP.

Comment: Oh! Sry... But not actually good in python. When I saw the css thing, I thought it was using in web development with PHP code.